# setState inside promise not updated

Tags: reactjs, promise, fetch-api

Why will the render function not update the state? See comments in code.
Inside the code I have a static comment out version, this works, but the dynamic function `get(..)`
doesn't update the State for the render function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Products from "./components/products";

import './App.css';

//function App() {
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    products: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const productsURL = 'http://wundp.192.168.43.67.xip.io/rest/products';


    const get = (url, key) => {
      fetch(url)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            /* this works and i see the data */
            console.log('1: ', data[key]);
   
            /* the state is not updated, why?  */
            this.setState({ key : data[key] })
          })
          .catch(console.log)
    }

    /* this fails, the state in the render function is later empty, why?  */
    get(productsURL, 'products');

    /* this works!
    fetch('http://wundp.192.168.43.67.xip.io/rest/products')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          this.setState({ products: data.products })
        })
        .catch(console.log)
    */
  }

  render() {
    /* this.state.products is empty, why?  */
    console.log('state: ',this.state.products);

    return  (
        <Products products={this.state.products} />
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: Because you're setting `this.state.key`, not `this.state[key]` (i.e. `this.state.products`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Feedback. Your Solution doesn't work.
It would give this error, because i don't use typescript.
 Line 13:  'int' is not defined

I found a solution, i have to wrap the key with []...
 this.setState({ [key] : data[key] })

then it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

update the state to

```
state = {
    products: [],
    key: int
}
```

then below code works - `this.setState({ key : data[key] })` --> setState will update properties which exist in the state.

```
const get = (url, key) => {
      fetch(url)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            this.setState({ key : data[key] })
          })
          .catch(console.log)
    }
```

Please let me know if any.